# azure linux vm times out while provisioning

Tags: ubuntu, azure, provisioning

I imported a vhd in azure containing ubuntu 14.04.

If i try to create a vm using that image, it shows 'Running (provisioning)' for a long time, and then eventually says 'Running (Provisioning timed out)'.

I cant even ssh into the machine once it gets in this state.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install [WALinuxAgent](https://github.com/Azure/WALinuxAgent) into your image? It's necessary for provisioning.

Complete tutorial: [Prepare an Ubuntu Virtual Machine for Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-create-upload-vhd-ubuntu/).

Comment: if you are talking about this step in the vm creation process, then i did leave the box checked. should i leave it unchecked? http://screencast.com/t/deZurBF0ATdZ

Comment: Uncheck it, please. Azure will try to connect your vm via protocol, that realized in WALinuxAgent due to this option. However, vm may have more problems, for example: your vm may not detect the network interface in azure. So, it's better to shutdown the image and download it for investigation (to see the logs).

Comment: it seems even unchecking doesnt solve the issue. is there any documentation on the right way to import a ubuntu vhd file?

Comment: Yes, [Prepare an Ubuntu Virtual Machine for Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-create-upload-vhd-ubuntu/).

Comment: are the instructions here specific to hyper-v in anyway? we are exporting from rackspace

Comment: Yes, WALinuxAgent + Kernel modules for Hyper-V. ps. Try to download your image from Azure and check the startup logs.

Comment: how do we check the logs? they are inside the os in vhd file right? not accessible till we can deploy the image on a vm if i am correct?

Comment: Yes, they are inside vm. Download image that filed to start, launch at the local machine and check the output of [dmesg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man8/dmesg.8.html) comamnd.